# What is the point of having a `MikroTik` tag?

Tags: discussion

Quoting [Ron Maupin](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/8499/ron-maupin):

> The community has decided that for hardware to be on-topic here, the manufacturer must offer optional, paid support. Unfortunately, MikroTik does not. […]

[Source](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/38381/33726)

### So, what is the point of having a [`MikroTik`](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mikrotik) tag, anyhow?

Right now, it seems more to be [a mouse trap to have your question closed](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mikrotik).

### Should the `MikroTik` be deleted in this community?

This would avoid an endless stream of similarly inappropriate questions.

Answer (score 1):

The community standards change. At the time this site started, the requirement for vendor support of the hardware wasn't in place. There are some questions and answers on the site that no longer meet the current standards set by the community. It just happens that MikroTik equipment is one of those. Unfortunately, it would be a huge effort to track down and close all the currently off-topic questions that have been answered on Network Engineering. In an ideal world, we would probably remove all those questions and related tags, but nobody really has the time.

Also, your question is really about a residential network, and that is something else that is off-topic. Each SE site maintains a [*What topics can I ask about here?*](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section in its [*Help Center*](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help), and that sections explains what is on-topic for the site.

As it says in that section:

> **Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about
>   professionally managed networks in a business environment.**

The reason Network Engineering was established was to allow network professionals a place to ask and answer those types of questions without wading through all the other question on Super User or Server Fault, where networking is also supported. Network Engineering and Server Fault support professionals, and those professionals have created standards for their respective sites. There is some overlap on the three sites, and even with Stack Overflow, to the degree that some network engineers on Network Engineering also offer help on those other sites.

We have tried to be courteous about your question being off-topic for Network Engineering, and a couple of people have directed you to Super User. It has been my experience that is more than you would get on Server Fault if you ask about home networking there, and it is certainly not the abuse you may get (as I have seen happen) on Stack Overflow.

The Super User community does a pretty good job of supporting home networking and consumer-grade devices.

Comment: This Meta question is no longer about my residential network question… The question is: **Should the `MikroTik` be deleted in this community?** This would avoid an endless stream of similarly inappropriate questions.

Comment: I answered the question, and I tried to give you more information, too, but you seem to have some type of attitude about this. Please, understand that we are simply trying to help you, but the community has imposed some constraints.

Comment: How about business environments that use top-grade MikroTik products like CCR1072 or incoming CRS317? I mean It's basically like saying that companies with smaller budget that don't use overpriced "enterprise" hardware are not professional enough to get help here. You know it's not really like buying Cisco automatically makes you "professional" company... I know that MTK makes a lot of SOHO grade devices but they also make carrier grade ones, that includes Cloud Core Router and Cloud Router Switch product series.

Comment: See the excellent answer to [this question](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/567/8499).

Comment: I'm absolutely not insisting on accepting SOHO etc. and I understand that it's not the right place, just like ServerFault. I just wanted to point out that problems involving MTK hardware _could_ in certain cases fall under big enterprise networks. I don't think paid support criteria is appropriate or even politically correct... I'm not linguist but most of people asking enterprise related questions on MTK forum seem to be from 3rd world countries. I know many companies (not startups but regular companies) in Poland that use MTK. It's just really weird requirement discriminating poor countries

Comment: I understand your point, but that is what the community decided, even before I joined. You are free to Ask a Meta question to see if the community has changed its mind. It comes up several times a year, but it never goes very far. [su] does a pretty good job of supporting consumer-grade devices, and [sf] does this for a business. Engineers from [networkengineering.se] participate on both those sites.

Comment: Maybe there's still a question here: is it technically possible to delete the MikroTik tag? If the answer is no, then there's nothing to add.

Comment: @JFL, apparently no way for even a moderator to delete an existing tag.

Comment: @JFL the only way for a tag to be removed is if the "system" removes it. AFAIK this will only happen if there are no questions (including deleted questions) associated with it for some period of time.

Comment: I feel the Microtik tags are causing instant closure - it may be justified I believe the Microtik support model which (in a purely my own opinion) meets the SU requirement is "hire a consultant who microtik have certified".  I would think a network with 100 machines is commercial .  Personally I have seen an industrial control site with Microtik.  Maybe  - I feel it may be if it is Mictotik that no longer immediately means it is offtopic? Should I be raising a separate question /vote ???

Comment: @Ross, unfortunately, MikroTik doesn't offer a paid support option, which is the requirement: "_hardware that has a paid support option (enterprise/provider class products, some small business class devices)_." As Ylearn has pointed out several times, it is not a perfect line to draw, but it is what we have. We are open to suggestions for other criteria, but it cannot be complex. There is a [question here](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/8499) where someone has tried to come up with alternatives.

Comment: Nope reconsidered , I don't think we should change the tag, I don't see any useful alternative having read all the comments and other meta discussion on this, image suggested add mikrotik is off topic to the tag

Answer (score 1):

Dues this being a recurrent question, it has been debated in the [Network Engineering Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations).

We may remove entirely he Mikrotig Tag from the site by removing it from all questions. The system will then automatically destroy the tag when it is no more associated with any question.

Comment: That has now happened, and the MikroTik tag is gone (at least until someone creates it again by placing it on a question).