# Cat 6a cable with 2 ports socket?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Cat 6a cable with 2 ports socket?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43652/cat-6a-cable-with-2-ports-socket)

My question was put on hold because "NE is a site for to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks in a business environment", and "Unfortunately, questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here".

I believe my case is not a typical, simple home networking example. A similar setup could be found in any office building. Actually, in an office that I used to rent had a setup like this one, but I used only one of the two ports in a socket.

Therefore, while my case is in regards to a house setup, the same setup could be found in a professional environment. That way, my question can be possibly a valid NE question.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your question is really about your home network which is explicitly off-topic here.

Additionally, despite the fact you could find such a setup in office building, this is in violation of the cabling standard.

I.E. it is not a professional way of cabling and many issue - really difficult to diagnose -  can arise due to this non-compliant setup.

This site is about professional networks maintained according to industry good practices. Such hacks fall out the scope of the site.

I'm sure many people will be happy to answer this question on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).